# Decode an UTF8 email header

Tags: perl, email, utf-8, header

I have an email subject of the form:

```
=?utf-8?B?T3.....?=
```

The body of the email is utf-8 base64 encoded - and has decoded fine.
I am current using Perl's Email::MIME module to decode the email.

What is the meaning of the =?utf-8 delimiter and how do I extract information from this string?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [`encoded-word`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) tokens (as per [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html)) can occur in values of some headers. They are parsed as follows:

```
=?<charset>?<encoding>?<data>?=
```

Charset is UTF-8 in this case, the encoding is `B` which means base64 (the other option is `Q` which means Quoted Printable).

To read it, first decode the base64, then treat it as UTF-8 characters.

Also read the various Internet Mail RFCs for more detail, mainly [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html).

Since you are using Perl, [Encode::MIME::Header](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::MIME::Header) could be of use:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> use Encode qw/encode decode/;
> $utf8   = decode('MIME-Header', $header);
> $header = encode('MIME-Header', $utf8);
> ```
>
> ABSTRACT
>
> This module implements RFC 2047 Mime
>   Header Encoding. There are 3 variant
>   encoding names; MIME-Header, MIME-B
>   and MIME-Q. The difference is
>   described below
>
> ```
>               decode()          encode()  
> MIME-Header   Both B and Q      =?UTF-8?B?....?=  
> MIME-B        B only; Q croaks  =?UTF-8?B?....?=  
> MIME-Q        Q only; B croaks  =?UTF-8?Q?....?=
> ```

Answer (score 17):

I think that the Encode module handles that with the `MIME-Header` encoding, so try this:

```
use Encode qw(decode);
my $decoded = decode("MIME-Header", $encoded);
```

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. Btw, I also used print encode('utf-8', $headers_decoded) to display decoded headers properly, if someone else is reading this while writing some mail script.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [RFC2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html). The 'B' means that the part between the last two '?'s is base64-encoded. The 'utf-8' naturally means that the decoded data should be interpreted as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

[MIME::Words](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Words) from MIME-tools work well too for this. I ran into some issue with Encode and found MIME::Words succeeded on some strings where Encode did not.

```
use MIME::Words qw(:all);
$decoded = decode_mimewords(
    'To: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?= <keld@dkuug.dk>',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard extension for charset labeling of headers, specified in [RFC2047](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=2047).