# Perl/MIME encoded text trouble

Tags: perl, mime

I have a MIME-encoded messages (in Maildir), that are having both base64-encoded headers (solved by lurking for related question ( [Decode an UTF8 email header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126070/decode-an-utf8-email-header) ), decode('MIME-Header', $val), main body in plain text and a text/plain base64 encoded data in the body;

It is said, that base64 data is encoded in utf-8.
However, when I do:

```
use MIME::Base4;
..
$decoded = decode_base64($block_from_line_array); # MIME body extracted from message's
$msgtext .= $decoded;
..
print decode('utf-8', $msgtext);
```

It seems that the block is decoded incorrectly.

```
print decode('utf-8', $msgtext); works ok, when message body is in utf-8
```

Attach:

```
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]
X-Mailer: http://www.we.praise.buggy.php.scripts.what.we.do.when.we.dont.do.us
X-MessageID: 140
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="b1_16819d4d69564bfc0185ed5b9508ad31"

<Here the body begins -- mhambra>
--b1_16819d4d69564bfc0185ed5b9508ad31
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
<MIME BLOCK>
```

Message is known to be displayed correctly in GMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a module like [Email::MIME](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-MIME/) to do the hard work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::MIME;

my $msg = Email::MIME->new($message_text);
print $msg->body;
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW Email::MIME seemed fragile for me on some example emails I was testing.  Email::Parser worked better for me trying to extract segments of text/html or text/plain that might be in base64 (and usually had transfer-encoding base64 / utf-8

```
use MIME::Parser;
use MIME::Base64;

sub flatten_parts {
    my ($mimePart, $fh) = @_;
    $fh or $fh = select;
    my $part;
    no strict 'refs';
    if($mimePart->mime_type =~ /text\/(plain|html)/i){
        my $base64=join('',@{$mimePart->body}); # This will be the base64 we're after.
        my $encoding = $mimePart->head->mime_encoding;
        if($encoding eq 'base64'){
                my $plainContent=MIME::Base64::decode_base64($base64);
                print $plainContent;
        }
    }   
    ### walk the parts:
    my @parts = $mimePart->parts;
    foreach $part (@parts) {
        flatten_parts($part, $fh);
    }
}
### Create a new parser object:
our $parser = new MIME::Parser;
### Parse an input filehandle:
$entity = $parser->parse(\*STDIN);
flatten_parts($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, if you happen to write a Greek lambda in an UTF8 formatted mail, `MIME::Parser` barfs, and there seems to be no known workaround — not even editing all the `*.pm` files, adding `use utf8;`, etc.

Try opening a new message in Thunderbird, attach some files, write that unicode character in the body and save it as a `.eml` file. `MIME::Parser` will throw an error.

See also [CPAN Bug #105377](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=105377).