# MIME::QuoterdPrint decodes everything but whitespaces in perl script

Tags: perl, character-encoding, decode, mime

I am writing a simple imap client with Perl's **Net::IMAP::Simple** module.
I'd like to print subjects of messages on standart output. The subject is encoded in Quoted-Printables, so I have to decode it with **MIME::QuotedPrint** *decode_qp()* function.
Everything is printed fine, except whitespaces, they remain encoded and I have no idea why. The output looks like this now:

```
[073] =?UTF-8?Q?[Myawesome_subject_topic]?= =?UTF-8?Q?_Сообщение?= =?UTF-8?Q?_номер?=
```

As you can see, whitespaces are locaed between ?= and =?UTF-8?Q?_ 'tags'.
Not sure how to deal with them. The code for the relevant part is below

```
my $nm = $imap->select('INBOX');
for (my $i = 1; $i <= $nm; $i++) {
if ($imap->seen($i)) {
    print '*';
} 
else {
    print " ";
}
my $es = Email::Simple->new(join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );
my $decoded = $es->header('Subject');
$decoded = decode_qp($decoded);
printf("[%03d] %s\n", $i, $decoded);
}
```

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

1. Use **Encode** module instead of **MIME::QuotedPrint**

   `use Encode qw(decode);`
2. Decode subject like this

   `$decoded = decode("MIME-Header", $encoded);`

additional info on the topic in the accepted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simple decode the full subject value with quoted-printable since not the full subject is encoded. If you have something like

```
 Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?AAAAAAAA?=   =?UTF-8?Q?BBBBBBBB?=
```

you have to take each of `=?CHENC?Q?ENCODED?=` separately, decode the `ENCODED` part as quoted-printable and then interpret the result depending on the character encoding `CHENC` (i.e. UTF-8 in your specific case). After this is done replace the whole `=?...?=` part with the decoded data.

For the exact details see [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). For an existing implementation in Perl see for example [Encode::MIME::Header](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/MIME/Header.html). See also [Decode an UTF8 email header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126070/decode-an-utf8-email-header).

Comment: You live - you learn. Solution via the link you provided works perfectly. Thanks.
Gotta read rfc for email specifications